# How to parse .trace(profiling android application) files into sql format

Tags: android, sql, database, trace, data-analysis

I am new at android development. I wanted to profile the performance of my application. So I have generated a log file(.trace) by adding the following code -

```
`// start tracing to "/sdcard/calc.trace"
Debug.startMethodTracing("calc");
// ...
// stop tracing
Debug.stopMethodTracing();`
```

Now, I have a calc.trace file. But I want for parse this file into sql format so that I can use advance queries to bring out information from the data. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the (.)trace file with the following ruby code that uses regex to parse the data into (.)sql file. It also provides a query to insert the data into your choice of SQL database.

But before that use the following command to convert the binary trace log into a txt file

> > /pathTotraceview/trceview -r filename.trace > filename.txt

Then save and run the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

@values = Array.new

STDIN.read.split("\n").each do |a|
   if a =~ /(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s([\w+.$]+)/
                 id = $1
                 tstart = $2
                 tend  = $3
                 gstart = $4
                 gend = $5
                 excl = $6
                 incl = $7
                 meth = $8
                 @values << "(#{id},#{tstart},#{tend},#{gstart},#{gend},#{excl},#{incl},'#{meth}')"
     end
end

puts "INSERT INTO table_name(pid,tstart,tend,gstart,gend,excl,incl,meth) values"
puts "#{@values.join(" , ")};"
```

To purse with this file store it in your work directory as toSQL.rb or any other name and use the following command in your terminal to generate sql dump:

> > cat traceFileName.txt | ./toSQL.rb > fileName.sql

Answer (score 0):

You can run sql queries on your android trace files using tool called Trace Processor
https://perfetto.dev/docs/quickstart/trace-analysis